# Which of the following input element variations will show a numeric keypad in mobile browsers?

Tags: html

what is the correct code. Any idea.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"/>

<input type="number"/>

<input type="text" keyboard="numeric"/>

<input type="text" keyboard="number11"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you just try them?!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following input, both will work:

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends. If you use `<input type="number">` the browser will render it as a numerical input containing the up and down buttons to cycle the value. If you want it to be only numbers, but without the buttons, then use the pattern.